# How to verify if a Kafka Topic is not empty meaning has at least 1 message?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am writing a little Kafka metrics exporter (Yes there are loads available like prometheus etc but I want a light weight custom one. Kindly excuse me on this).

As part of this **I would like to know as soon as first message is received (or topic has messages) in a Kafka topic**. I am using Spring Boot and Kafka.

I have the below code which gives the name of the topic and number of partitions. I want to know if the topic has messages? Kindly let me know how can I get this stat. Any lead is much appreciated!

```
 @ReadOperation
public List<TopicManifest> kafkaTopic() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    ListTopicsOptions listTopicsOptions = new ListTopicsOptions();
    listTopicsOptions.listInternal(true);

    ListTopicsResult listTopicsResult = adminClient.listTopics(listTopicsOptions);

    Set<String> topics = listTopicsResult.names().get().stream().filter(topic -> !topic.startsWith("_")).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    System.out.println(topics);

    DescribeTopicsResult describeTopicsResult = adminClient.describeTopics(topics);
    Map<String, KafkaFuture<TopicDescription>> topicNameValues = describeTopicsResult.topicNameValues();
   List<TopicManifest> topicManifests =  topicNameValues.entrySet().stream().map(entry -> {
        try {
            TopicDescription topicDescription = entry.getValue().get();
            return TopicManifest.builder().name(entry.getKey())
                                          .noOfPartitions(topicDescription.partitions().size())
                   
                                          .build();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return topicManifests;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `KafkaConsumer` and call `endOffsets` (the consumer does not need to be subscribed to the topic(s)).

```java
@Bean
ApplicationRunner runner1(ConsumerFactory cf) {
    return args -> {
        try (Consumer consumer = cf.createConsumer()) {
            System.out.println(consumer.endOffsets(List.of(new TopicPartition("ktest29", 0),
                    new TopicPartition("ktest29", 1),
                    new TopicPartition("ktest29", 2))));
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: That doesn't guarantee all messages before the end offset haven't been removed due to retention

Comment: @OneCricketeer I tried the above and it works like what I expect but can you please elaborate the problem?

Comment: He means that a non-zero ending offset does not actually mean there might be records in the partition (they all might have expired and been removed by the broker). If that's a problem, you can `assign()` the partition(s) and try to receive one record from each.

Answer (score 0):

Offsets stored on the topic never reduce. Getting the end offset doesn't guarantee you have a non-empty topic (start and end offsets for the topic partitions could be the same).

Instead, you will still create a consumer but set

```
auto.offset.reset=earliest
group.id=UUID.randomUUID()
```

Then `subscribe` and run

```
ConsumerRecords records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
boolean empty = records.count() == 0;
```

By setting `auto.offset.earliest` with a random group, you are guaranteed to start at the earliest offset and seek to the first available record, if it exists, at which point, you can try to poll any number of records, to see if any are returned within the specified timeout.

This should work for regular and compacted topics without needing to check committed offsets.